# Setting up repeat action. Am lost if its a Loop or Do or ? Statement

Tags: excel, vba

'I need this to repeat the copy and paste process across columns until counter
'= either key page, "book" cell or reads from row 1, if row 1# = key"book"#

'Next column(Page) should be 3columns from last copy/Pasted column

```
"PicPg" B2 copies to "PrntPg" B2
E2 to E2
etc
```

**This is my very first post in any forum to ask for help. Forgive the ignorance.
I'll try and answer any questions the best I can.
Thank you in advanced for your time and help!

I can share the workbook, just not sure how.

```
Sub createPrintPage()
 
    With Worksheets("PicPg").Cells(2, 2)
        .Copy
        Sheets("PrntPg").Pictures.Paste(Link:=True).Select

        With Worksheets("PrntPg").Cells(2, 5)
            .Select
       
            Worksheets("PicPg").Cells(2, 5).Copy
            Sheets("PrntPg").Pictures.Paste(Link:=True).Select
         
        End With
    End With
        
 End Sub
```

'the "For i", I have not figured out yet. I have been trying to get it to
'continue repeating.... I've tried to play with for i's... I get lost
'this with statement seems to be working, now to get it to continue across.
'this is day 3 ive researched, Tried many ways... and can only get this far (and this
'is much MUCH prettier(ie:Simplier) then where I began.

Comment: This is working for the copy and paste, again, do I use an For statement here, if so, at which level?

Sub try2()

shPicPg.Cells(2, 2).CopyPicture
 
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
        End With
        
shPrintPg.Cells(2, 5).Select

shPicPg.Cells(2, 5).CopyPicture
    
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
        End With
           
  
End Sub

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean by looping across columns. Then you talk about rows? What is key page? What is "book" cell? Try to write a simple problem statement and maybe the answer will jump out at you.

Comment: You have given me alot to play with, thank you!

The book and key, is something for later i think... Its what I want my counter to be, its on a different sheet. Sorry for the confusion there.

I have two next statements, only difference is which cell it is coping and where it pastes to.. I will play with your suggestions and let you know my updates... thank you again!

Comment: I understand you are happy about finding a solution, but you cannot [post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75381660/4) it in the question, as it won't be a question anymore. If you want to share the solution, post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

both method is used to loop and iterate. if you want to use For just give it a beginning and an ending

```
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 0 To 3
        'put your code in here and it will loop 4x (i = 0, i = 1, i = 2 and i = 3)
    Next i
    
    'you can put your condition for the loop to exit either at the Do or Loop by using until
    i = 0
    
    Do Until i = 3
        'although start from 0, but it will loop 3x because when it hit i = 3 it will stop (i = 0, i = 1, i = 2 and i = 3)
        i = i + 1 'remember to increment your counter, before leaving the loop the counter had changed to 1 
    Loop
    
    i = 0
    
    Do
        'although start from 0, but it will loop 3x because when it hit i = 3 it will stop (i = 0, i = 1, i = 2 and i = 3)
        i = i + 1 'remember to increment your counter
    Loop Until i = 3
```

there is also a lot more different ways to write it.

you can use cell iteration to do your loop

```
    Dim cell As Object 'late binding, early binding can write Dim cell as range
        
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Range("A1:A20")
        'do something
    Next cell
```

you can even use your own condition to set the stop

```
Do
    If x = 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Range("A1").Value = "True"
    End If
Loop Until ThisWorkbook.Range("A1") = "True"
```

you can even Exit Do or Exit For if you have already achieved your desired outcome.

```
Dim i as Integer, temp as string

For i = 0 To 3
    If ThisWorkbook.Range("A" & i).Value2 = "True" Then
        temp = "hey, I found what I am looking for"
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Hi there, Im not sure if you will see this... THANK YOU for your help!! I updated my question... its working VERY WELL... I still have things to work on, but the guts are coming together nicely and you helped!!